# Saving a dictionary to a text file python 3

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I am trying to complete a college assignment, to save a dictionary to a text file. Here is the save function, using the same formula my instructor provided:

```
def saveData(orders):
    
    filename = input("Filename to save: ")
    
    print("Saving data...")
    
    outFile = open(filename, "wt")
    
    for x in orders.keys():
        order = orders[x].getorder()
        amount = orders[x].getamount()
        name = str(orders[x].getname())
        outFile.write(order + "," + amount + "," + name + "\n")
```

And here is the error:

```
 File "main.py", line 49, in saveData                                                                                                                                                 
    outFile.write(order + "," + amount + "," + name + "\n")                                                                                                                            
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: `outFile.write(f"{order},{amount},{name}\n")`

Comment: Just cast amount as a String: str(amount)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the line

```
outFile.write(order + "," + amount + "," + name + "\n")
```

With

```
outFile.write(str(order )+ "," + str(amount )+ "," + str(name) + "\n")
```

This should solve that error.

Answer (score 0):

`amount` is probably an integer and you can't perform string concatenation or integer operations between strings and integers. Try casting this value to a string like this.

```
outFile.write(order + "," + str(amount) + "," + name + "\n")
```

If it's still giving you trouble then try doing the same to `order` too

Comment: I think order is also int or float. Just change it to str or use f string to write

Comment: Weird it doesn't for me. Can you share what the error says?

Answer (score 0):

Use f string option to write to file.

Replace the line:

```
outFile.write(order + "," + amount + "," + name + "\n")
```

with

```
outFile.write(f"{order},{amount},{name}\n")
```

Alternate, you can write the entire dictionary as follows:

```
orders = {'a':25,'b':35,'c':'test'}

with open('file.txt', 'w+') as outFile:
    outFile.write(str(orders))
```

The above line will write the entire dictionary into the file.

The output in the file will be as follows:

```
{'a': 25, 'b': 35, 'c': 'test'}
```

Can you share some of the data in your dictionary?